# How do I open an .rptproj in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, projects-and-solutions

I have a Visual Studio 2010 solution that contains an `.rptproj` type of project. One of my colleagues is able to open that solution in Visual Studio 2010 SP1 just fine. I've seen it work. However, when I try to do it, I get

> "this type of project is not supported by this version of the application"

I am able to open the solution from SQL Server Business Intelligence Studio 2008 just fine.

We both have VS2010 Ultimate SP1 and SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise. Full installs for both products. When you go to his Help -> About dialog on Visual Studio, it lists

- SQL Server Analysis Services
- SQL Server Reporting Services
- and SQL Server Integration Services

On my VS2010, those do not show up, but they do on my the SQL Server BI Studio About dialog. I tried uninstalling everything and reinstallling it, but to no avail.

Comment: I'm confused. with your solution marked. Those templates (rptproj) can be openen in VS 2010 ? @szymon say that templates for SSRS added to vS 2008 not VS 2010. Did you tried?.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What I had to to do is to install Business Intelligence Development Studio from SQL Server 2008 installer (specifically, I used 2008 R2). See the screenshot below.

That added the templates for SSRS to Visual Studio 2008.

Note, you have to have VS 2008 SP 1 installed (at least for SQL Server 2008 R2).

[image]

Comment: Those templates (rptproj) can be openen in VS 2010 ? You say that templates for SSRS added to vS 2008 not VS 2010. I'm confused.

Comment: @Kiquenet I was using VS2008 at the time. I'm not working on that now, I cannot check it again.

Answer (score 6):

[SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272686%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) is a free add on to Visual Studio / SQL Server that supports reporting projects, so this may give you what you need.  I have only used it for Database projects and not reporting projects, so I am not certain if it will be the solution in this scenario, but give it a shot.  When we upgraded to Visual Studio 2010 back in 2010, this did not exist, so we moved our reporting into a separate VS2008 solution, so that's always a (non-ideal) solution.

Comment: Note that confusingly, there are 2 releases of SSDT for the Visual 2010 release: one as you say is for DB projects and is downloadable as a freestanding addition, but does *not* include or support the editing of SSRS reports.  The other, (confusingly) also labelled as SSDT and sometimes referred to as SSDT for BI, is only accessible from and included in SQL Server 2012 installation media.  Start SQL Server 2012 installer and install the "SSDT" option, then you'll get the VS2010 shell if you don't have it yet and will get the required to be able to edit .rptproj projects of that vintage.

Answer (score 5):

As it turns out, I had incomplete information. My colleague had SQL Server 2012 installed as well on his machine. That SQL install is what made the SQL Server XXX Services show up on his Visual Studio 2010 install.

From what I gather, SQL Server 2008 R2 install would give the older version of Visual Studio the capability to open that SQL version of .rptproj projects. That is, SQL 2008 R2 would give Visual Studio 2008 to open SQL Server 2008 R2 .rptprojects, while SQL Server 2012 gives the option to open SQL Server 2008 R2 .rptprojects.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add, I was able to do it with the following steps as shown in this question.
Now you can use Visual Studio 2010 to edit reports.

[Are SSRS Reports supported in Visual Studio 2010 or 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333459/is-there-any-inbuilt-localization-resources-support-in-ssrs-using-visual-studio)

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I've been tearing my hair out trying to resolve this issue, and that link worked perfectly.